# Scala implementation of @rolfl's integer-partitioning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scala, comparative-review, combinatorics, iterator

While reviewing @Martijn's [*Distinct sums of integers*](/q/115687/9357) (finding all combinations of positive integers that sum to a given number), I proposed the following [solution](/a/118477/9357):

```
/** List of non-increasing positive integers */
type Sum = List[Int]

def sums(n: Int): Iterator[Sum] = {
  /** Prepends the head of the stack repeatedly until a total amount has
    * been added.  The leading element of the result is then increased
    * so that the total added is exactly the specified amount.
    */
  @tailrec
  def topUp(amount: Int, stack: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (amount < stack.head)
      (stack.head + amount) :: stack.tail
    else
      topUp(amount - stack.head, stack.head :: stack)
  }

  /** Returns the next partition by popping the first element, increasing the
    * next element, and topping it up to the same total.  Returns None if
    * the input has only one element.
    */
  def advance(partition: Option[Sum]): Option[Sum] = {
    partition.get match {
      case List(n) => None
      case p       => Some(topUp(p.head - 1, p.tail.head + 1 :: p.tail.tail))
    }
  }

  Iterator.iterate(Some(List.fill(n)(1)): Option[Sum])(advance)
          .takeWhile(! _.isEmpty)
          .map(_.get)
}
```

Example run:

```
scala> sums(5).foreach(println)
List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
List(2, 1, 1, 1)
List(3, 1, 1)
List(2, 2, 1)
List(4, 1)
List(3, 2)
List(5)
```

I'm pretty satisfied with the algorithm, as it is based on a [Java solution that was devised by @rolfl](/a/36827/9357).

However, I'm not happy about the way I've expressed it in Scala, particularly with regards to the termination of the iterator.

- Is there a way to write `topUp` without explicit recursion, yet still avoiding `:::` concatenation?
- Is the `: Option[Sum]` type annotation on `Some(List.fill(n)(1))` avoidable?
- There seems to be a lot of `Option` / `None` / `Some` noise in `advance`.  Is there a better way to handle the termination condition?  (Perhaps by using `lift`?)
- Similarly, `Iterator.iterate(…)(…).takeWhile(! _.isEmpty).map(_.get)` seems cumbersome.  Is there a less verbose way to say "repeatedly apply this function until exhausted" using the standard Scala library?

---

For the record, instead of `advance` and `Iterator.iterate(…).takeWhile(…).map(…)`, I had previously written it this way, using explicit recursion:

```
def makeSums(partition: Sum): Stream[Sum] = {
  partition #:: (partition match {
    case List(n) => Stream.Empty
    case p       => makeSums(topUp(p.head - 1, p.tail.head + 1 :: p.tail.tail))
  })
}

makeSums(List.fill(n)(1))
```

… which returned a `Stream[Sum]` instead of an `Iterator[Sum]`.  Note that it's not tail-recursive.  (I also [tried to write it as a self-referential stream](//stackoverflow.com/q/35111887/1157100), but couldn't figure out how to terminate it.)

I think that, despite being longer, the `Iterator.iterate(…)` solution is better because it decouples the "repeated application" aspect from the "produce the next result" aspect.  Your opinion on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Keep in mind that I likely know less about scala than you and that this is my first review ;)</sub>

> Is there a way to write `topUp` without explicit recursion, yet still avoiding `:::` concatenation?

I don't think so, but I may be wrong.

> Is the `: Option[Sum]` type annotation on `Some(List.fill(n)(1))` avoidable?

Yes! You can use the `Option` type constructor like this:

```
Iterator.iterate(Option(List.fill(n)(1)))(advance)
```

> There seems to be a lot of `Option / None / Some` noise in advance. Is there a better way to handle the termination condition? (Perhaps by using `lift`?)

I think so, but not with lift. This just uses the standard `map` and `filter` (please let me know if this is incorrect logic).

```
def advance(partition: Option[Sum]): Option[Sum] =
   partition.filter(_.size > 1)
            .map(p => topUp(p.head - 1, p.tail.head + 1 :: p.tail.tail))
```

> Similarly, `Iterator.iterate(…)(…).takeWhile(! _.isEmpty).map(_.get)` seems cumbersome. Is there a less verbose way to say "repeatedly apply this function until exhausted" using the standard Scala library?

I really don't know.

One minor point. Here

```
Iterator.iterate(Some(List.fill(n)(1)): Option[Sum])(advance)
        .takeWhile(! _.isEmpty)
        .map(_.get)
```

You use `! _.isEmpty`, but option has a perfect method for you, [`isDefined`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).